# Go to file member in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am currently looking for a way to navigate in Intellij to a file member. This functionallity is at least possible with Resharper. 
In IntelliJ I only found a feature to globally navigate to a symbol (Navigate -> Symbol...). Is there a way to limit this view to the currently opened file?

Answer (score 1):

With *Navigate --> Symbol*, you can only filter by file type rather than scope.

However, you can look at the panel on the right where your project is and click the gear for Settings. Then select *Show Members*.

Comment: I dont see how find usage should help me? I have a file with function "foo" and I want to navigate to this function by typing "foo" into a navigation box.

Comment: So that means there is no way to jump directly to a method by just typing the name? I know that I can navigate to the project view by keybinding and then type the method but I somehow would prefer a more direct way of navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using «File Structure Pop-up». It can be opened:

- using the `Navigate => File Structure` menu item.
- using the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

References:

1. [Navigation In Source Code, IntelliJ IDEA 15.0 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigation-in-source-code.html).
2. [Navigating with Structure Views, IntelliJ IDEA 15.0 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-with-structure-views.html).